# 'Automatic integrity protection' not visible in Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

I'm trying to enable the new 'Automatic integrity protection' feature for my Android app using the steps in the [docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10183279). My app meets all the listed prerequisites and I've prepared a release as described (already over 2 weeks ago):

- I opted in to Play App Signing (already since the first release of the app)
- I published an Android App Bundle (for this new version)
- The new version target a minimum API Level of 21

Strangely, I do not see anything related to this feature on the release's page or on the general "App integrity" page. There should be some details in both places about the new 'Automatic integrity protection' feature, according to the docs and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b31I65iPs7c) about the feature, but the "Automatic integrity protection" tab is simply not visible on my end at all:

[image: Screenshot of "App integrity" screen in Google Play Developer Console showing "Automatic integrity protection" tab]

I've already contacted Google Play Developer Support, and they couldn't say more than the feature (apparently) being unavailable.

Does anyone have similar experiences? Did the feature appear after some time, or did you find some trick to make it appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The video description says that the feature automatic integrity protection is currently available to a limited number of developers in the Google Play Console. You can try contacting Google Play developer support[1] or a Google Play partner manager to request access. Otherwise, you can also consider using the new Play Integrity API (https://g.co/play/integrityapi) if your app or game is online to detect risky/fraudulent interactions.

If contacting Google Play developer support did not help, it probably means the developer is not eligible for Automatic Integrity Protections or they are not expanding the program right now. In this case, please look out for more news later this year as it becomes available to more developers.

Disclaimer: I am part of the Automatic Integrity Protections team.

1: Via the Play Console or via https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/gethelp

Answer (score 0):

Now you can enable this api
In the last two weeks I found out that Google has opened up the Play Integrity API
The api documentation address is as follows：
https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/overview